# Save Display Configuration, depending on the connected Displays

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I was wondering why Ubuntu does not save the Display Configuration, depending on the connected Displays.

I have a Laptop using a Dockingstation. If the Laptop is connected to the Dockingstation I want a different Display Configuration than when my Laptop is not connected to the Dockingstation.

Why is this not the default behavior?

I am using the NVIDIA Driver 331.38. I set the display configuration in the nvidia-settings.

Comment: Are you using nvidia-settings or the Display section in the System Settings to set the display configuration?

Comment: @muru The nvidia-settings+

Comment: For me, it does save whatever settings I set via the Display section. `nvidia-settings` does its own thing and if it doesn't save the configuration, it maybe a bug or simply not a provided feature.

Comment: @muru Thank you. You are right. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @muru, I figured  that setting the Display Configuration using the integrated Ubuntu solution works fine. Therefore, it seems that this is a missing feature of the nvidia-settings.

Comment: Changing the display mode with `Super + P`, the dedicated display mode button or directly with `xrandr` have the same problem. Ubuntu will remember the display configuration only if it was made with the `Displays` application.

Comment: Woah, `Super` + `P` worked for me!